# Parrallel.For loop is executing slower than for

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've written two simple loops.

One is using the standard 'for':

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Second is using Parrallel.For, which suppose to be faster:

```
sw.Restart();
            Parallel.For(0,1000000,i =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    });              

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Unfortunately, it takes about 53 seconds for the first to execute, and about 1 minute and 50 seconds to the second (!!!).

Why is that and what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Because the threads have to synchronize in order to write to console? Try doing some actual work instead.

Comment: at first, there was a db writing instead of that writing to console, and it still performed slower.

Comment: Well, db is also a shared resource that makes locks/synchronization to occur. To get a perormance benefit you should try avoiding such resources in your parallel code.

Comment: Can you give an example or a piece of code for not causing synchronization to occur ?

Comment: Your error is believing that writing to the console should benefit from parallelization.

Comment: The code for `Console.WriteLine()` HAS A LOCK TO PREVENT MULTIPLE THREADS from accessing it at once. That lock will undo any parallelism you might get from `Parallel.For()` (Note that this has NOTHING to do with any code in the implementation of `Parallel.For()` which doesn't know anything about the code in `Console.WriteLine()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in linqpad I got 9 secs using the for statements and 12.5 secs using the Parallel.For

when you try to access a I/O resource like a database or a console output you have to synchronize your threads, using lock mechanism. Anyway I'd not recommend to access in parallel the database for insert or select statement.

However try your code with this change:

```
 Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
 StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

 for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
 {
      str.AppendLine(i.ToString());
 }

 sw.Stop();
 Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

 str = new StringBuilder();
 sw.Restart();

 Parallel.For(0,1000000,i =>
                {
                    str.AppendLine(i.ToString());
                });              

 sw.Stop();
 Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

this will drop the time to a couple of hundred of milliseconds.

Answer (score 4):

`Parallel.For` is not supposed to make a loop faster. It's supposed to make its iterations execute *in parallel*.

In your attempts, you've used code that uses resources that can't match any speed boost that would have been offered by parallelizing the loops (maybe because they need synchronization, maybe because there's not enough bandwidth, etc). Therefore, you're just having threads contest for a resource that can't keep up with them. Your scenarios simply don't call for parallelism (at least not the way you're attempting).

If you want to get an idea of how `Parallel.For` could boost the performance of a loop, consider doing some calculation inside the loop that saves the result to an exclusive (for each iteration) index in an array and make sure those calculations don't depend on the results of other iterations in any way.

Answer (score 1):

With parallel programming you can do more work at the same time. It causes your code to execute parallel. When you first look at parallel programming you expect your speed to increase linear. like 4 cores is 4 times faster.

However this only occurs when you have the most ideal code for parallel programming. Very few algorithms have this.

The total speed up of your code is limited by the portion of code that cannot be parallelized. Like stated before in comments and answers, For a Console.WriteLine or Database acces your threads have to syncronize. So this portion cannot be parallelized. If you have code in which a very large portion can't be executed parallel then the code can even execute slower than a normal loop. (the time used to syncronize the threads).

Amdhal's law gives us this conclusion.

> It states that a small portion of the program which cannot be parallelized will limit the overall speed-up available from parallelization

read more about Amdhal's law here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing